# ReactJS - this.state.[object].map is not a function?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Why do I get this error on a live server:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.state.navitems.map is not a function

But I never get this error on my localhost.

The reactjs:

```
import React from 'react'; import $ from 'jquery';

import NavItem from './nav-item';

class Footer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            navitems: [],
        };
    }

    // Then fetch the data using $.get():
    componentDidMount() {
        this.serverRequest = $.get(this.props.source, function (result) {
            this.setState({
                navitems: result
            });
        }.bind(this));
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.serverRequest.abort();
    }

    render() {
        var loop = this.state.navitems.map(function(item, index){
            return <NavItem key={index} item={item}></NavItem>;
        });

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="nav">
                    <ul>{ loop }</ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    } }

export { Footer as default }
```

Any ideas how I can fix this?

**EDIT:**

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log('props.source', this.props.source);
    this.serverRequest = $.get(this.props.source, function (result) {
        console.log('returned result', result);
        this.setState({
            navitems: result
        });
    }.bind(this));
}
```

result:

```
props.source ./data/nav.json

returned result [{
    "navId": "1",
    "title": "Home",
    "code": "home",
    "href": null,
    "style": null,
    "sort": "1",
    "url": "#",
    "parentId": null,
    "totalChildren": "0",
    "createdOn": null,
    "updatedOn": null
}, {
    "navId": "2",
    "title": "About",
    "code": "about",
    "href": null,
    "style": null,
    "sort": "2",
    "url": "#",
    "parentId": null,
    "totalChildren": "0",
    "createdOn": null,
    "updatedOn": null
}, {
    "navId": "3",
    "title": "Contact",
    "code": "contact",
    "href": null,
    "style": null,
    "sort": "3",
    "url": "contact",
    "parentId": null,
    "totalChildren": "0",
    "createdOn": null,
    "updatedOn": null
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess your problem probably lies here:

```
// Then fetch the data using $.get():
componentDidMount() {
    this.serverRequest = $.get(this.props.source, function (result) {
        this.setState({
            navitems: result
        });
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Have you been able to inspect what `this.props.source` equals? If it is correct, are you having any cross domain request problems? Add in some logging and see what the inspector gives you:

```
// Then fetch the data using $.get():
componentDidMount() {
    console.log('props.source', this.props.source);
    this.serverRequest = $.get(this.props.source, function (result) {
        console.log('returned result', result);
        this.setState({
            navitems: result
        });
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Comment: what is a cross domain request problem btw?

Comment: If it is caused by a cross-domain, “CORS”, problem you will need to set the correct headers on the server that is sending the request back to you. Add the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` on requests might work but be careful you are not opening your server up to unexpected requests.

Comment: MDN has some good documentation on it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: I do get the result I want with that console.log. but it is a text instead of object! Why?? See my edit above. thanks.

Comment: Maybe your server isn't setting the correct `Content-type`? I think if it is set to `application/json` then jQuery will automatically convert it to an object for you.

Comment: i think you are right. how do I `Add the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to reactJS?

Comment: You add it on the server, not on the client. Have a look at the MDN link @casr posted.

Comment: @kouak gone through that. but i m lost. how do i need it to the server - it is a request for json file only!?

Comment: The browser will not allow it unless the server you are accessing has given permission (i.e. via `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`).

Answer (score 0):

My quick solution - `$.getJSON`:

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.serverRequest = $.getJSON(this.props.source, function (result) {
            this.setState({
                article: result
            });
        }.bind(this));
    }
```